# Raspberry Pi 2, root access denied

Tags: raspberry-pi, root, sudo, raspbian

I have been playing with my raspberry pi 2 for about a week now. I am a beginner at it so I am learning as i go. I have been watching youtube videos of people doing projects and following there step by step guides but I keep running into the same problems.

I have been using rasbian as the OS, and I am having several problems with root access being denied. I am logged in as the basic user= pi , password = raspberry. So from my reading I have done I should be able to (using sudo), make root commands or accessing the root folder.

I have been trying to edit files using commands like

```
     sudo vim /root/.asoundrc
```

Whenever i do this i get a page that looks like this-

```
   ~
   ~
   ~
   ~
   ~
   ~
   ~
   ~
   "~/.asoundrc" [New File]                               0,0-1    All
```

and nothing will come up for me to edit

My other problem is using the command yaourt
Example:

```
yaourt -S jasper-tts-google
```

i get back

```
-bash: yaourt: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use yaourt unless you install it first. And it cannot be found in the standard repository. You have to install it manually.
As for the editing files. Try using a simpler editor like nano.
To be honest you seem way to newbish to be here. You need to have at least some basic understanding of how a Linux distro works. Vi is an commandline editor and very convenient when you don't have a Desktop Environment.
We can't help you much on this forum since you simply know too little and we can't hold your hand every step of the way if you can't do simple commands/things such as:

- Changing directory
- Editing files
- Change ownerships of files
- Sudo
- SSH
- (un)Installing software using the commandline(aptitude)
- Install software without using aptitude.

At least read about what you're trying to do. You should know what yaourt i before installing it. And with every installation of some software from yaourt - you need to have some kind of basic knowledge of PKGBUILD.

Answer (score 1):

So, as far as the first problem, you are opening a file that doesn't exist, so naturally it is an empty file.

`yaourt` is not installed by default, so naturally you must install it.